# One Giant Shader VS Many Small Shaders

Tags: shaders, graphics, software-engineering, graphics-programming

I am building forward rendering engine combined with atlas shadow map technique.

My goal is to build an engine that is capable of rendering similar scenes from games such as..
Doom
[image]
Overwatch
[image]

So I wonder, do I need to write one giant shader that does all? or do I have many different shaders for each different materials?

Comment: Definitely more than one shader, but probably not separate ones for different materials.

Comment: Both ubershader and highly individualized shader strategies are successfully used in large games. And given that you're using forward rendering, you don't have a strong constraint forcing you to a single shader (unless you prefer that route for other reasons). So you're largely able to pick your own route here. Have you had any difficulty implementing your favoured style that we might be able to help you overcome?

Comment: @DMGregory I do have experience making giant shader and individual small shaders. I had a conversation in chat and learned that it would be beneficial that I don't write each shader individually by typing them but rather make my own "shader compiling codes" somewhat like that of shaderlab?

Comment: I'm pretty sure both companies provide tools for their artists to easily create shaders though. Most likely having some standard shader structure and minimal uniform requirements. I doubt ubershaders are specifically implemented nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

Counting the shaders in my current application, there are 90 of which 37 perform screen rendering. The rest perform preparation of various tasks for those 37 shaders, or execute GPGPU. Practically all shaders are invoked during application run, a little bit depending on situation.

I don't see any great advantage with doing the screen render with such an ubershader. The only advantage would imho be enforcing strictness in the architecture and hardware usage, by intentionally limiting. This may be a good thing under certain circumstances, where such strictness is needed.

Such a shader may perform faster because of it's strictness, but today's hardware + (graphics drivers, OS) should gain little from it. Branching by sent-in boolean in the shader is fast but so is shader-switching and branching by calculation result or even texture lookup inside the shader. After all, we talk about hugely minor time slices.

Imho, the reasons for using such an ubershader are more architecture- and development policy-related than performance- and visual quality-related. It is probably the last thing i would personally go for, as I am usually worried about [painting myself into a corner](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/paint+into+a+corner). To me, an ubershader sounds like a nightmare.

This doesn't mean that there should be a separate shader for every single bit. One shader takes care of something that not any other shader takes care of, or something coming from a time and space mismatch with other shaders.